# Chart Macro In User Macro With Dynamic Content

Tags: confluence

I was trying to use the Chart macro inside user macro by using the following code,

```
## @noparams
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="chart">
              <ac:parameter ac:name="type">line</ac:parameter>
              <ac:parameter ac:name="Tables">Sample</ac:parameter>
</ac:structured-macro>

<table id="sample">

                 ... body goes here...

</table>
```

I am getting `No Data Available` in my confluence page. How can I provide the data to a chart macro dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andre from atlassian community answered my question. We can make use of `<ac:rich-text-body>` tag to provide the table. Syntax is following,

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="chart">
     <ac:parameter ac:name="type">line</ac:parameter> 
     <ac:rich-text-body>
         here goes the table
     </ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

Full discussion is available in [this url](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Chart-Macro-In-User-Macro-With-Dynamic-Content/qaq-p/710733#M95238).